# Will overstayed tourist in US be deported if reported?

Tags: deportation

My wife has a psychopathic ex-husband who has been in the country illegally for over four years. He guilts and confuses their children and is inappropriate in several areas when they visit him.  Came as a tourist, so didn't even need a visa, but has never left. He has been subtly extorting her for money since he doesn't work and they have joint custody. Even though there are tens of thousands of illegal Mexicans around him working every day, he claims he cannot work as he is here illegally. He has cost the medical system here many thousands of dollars in hospital bills, yet recently my wife found out he has 60,000US in a bank account that he obviously hasn't declared while in emergency rooms filling out forms. Really a scumbag. Can I report him with any success of his being deported due to the fact that he came here as a tourist on a three week visit and never left? If so, how would I start the process?

Comment: Illegal aliens are far more likely to be deported of they are committing crimes such as fraud. If you can get him in trouble with the regular police, the likelihood that it will end in his expulsion from the country increases significantly.

Comment: Lots of questions here. Why doesn't your wife simply stop permitting the children to visit the ex? If he is here illegally he is unlikely to try to fight the issue in court. What do you mean by "inappropriate" with the children? Some "inappropriate" actions will get him locked up. But finally this is nothing to do with travel.

Comment: If you remove all the stuff about the specific person and his behavior, the base question of "if I overstay in the US as a tourist, can a regular citizen (as opposed to law enforcement) report me to immigration & customs officials?" would be on topic, I think.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Well, you can report him, I don't know the probability that he'll actually be deported. Probably fairly high if you provide enough detail on where to find him.

> If you would like to report illegal aliens, please call Immigration and Customs Enforcement (ICE) at 1-866-DHS-2ICE (347-2423). They will need to know names, locations (either work place or residence) and any other specific information you can provide. Visit www.ice.gov for more information.

https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/735/~/reporting-illegal-activity